# How can I render a component in its own component (recursively) in svelte?

Tags: recursion, svelte

I'm trying to make a recursive component that acts as a sort of tree view, where the component takes in an array.

`App.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import Tree from "./Tree.svelte"
    let name = 'world';
</script>

<Tree arrayTree={[1, 2, [3, 4], 5, 6, 7, [8, [9, 10]], 11, 12]}/>
```

`Tree.svelte`

```html
<script>
    export let arrayTree = []
    export let level = 0
</script>

{#each arrayTree as branch}
    {#if Array.isArray(branch)}
        <!-- How do I do this? -->
    {:else}
        <p>{'-'.repeat(level)}{branch}</p>
    {/if}
{/each}
```

My goal is to re-render the component inside, but I can't re-call `<Tree>` inside the component, or else it says: `Tree is not defined`. Is there any way that I can accomplish this?

[Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6b2d9edf4b3346378c9831ef7d4c3aca?version=3.52.0)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`<svelte:self>`](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-self):

`App.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import Tree from "./Tree.svelte"
    let name = 'world';
</script>

<Tree arrayTree={[1, 2, [3, 4], 5, 6, 7, [8, [9, 10]], 11, 12]}/>
```

`Tree.svelte`

```html
<script>
    export let arrayTree = []
    export let level = 0
</script>

{#each arrayTree as branch}
    {#if Array.isArray(branch)}
        <svelte:self arrayTree={branch} level={level + 1}/>
    {:else}
        <p>{'-'.repeat(level)}{branch}</p>
    {/if}
{/each}
```

[Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/590a5819c067436586c0a44ca59a74c9?version=3.52.0)