# recursion not possible in case of compiling into custom components

Tags: svelte

i'am trying to build a tree view using recursion.
i followed the sample
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74166756/how-can-i-render-a-component-in-its-own-component-recursively-in-svelte)
and it works fine. But when i build it as a custom Web component (the compile option customElement:true and tag option to define an elements name) it produces a runtime error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot instantiate a custom element inside its own constructor during upgrades
```

Is this a general restriction in svelte or is there a special hack to solve the problem?

```
<svelte:options tag="my-tree" />

<script>
        export let arraytree;
        export let level = 0;

        let aTree = JSON.parse(arraytree);
</script>

{#each aTree as branch}
        {#if Array.isArray(branch)}
              <svelte:self arraytree={JSON.stringify(branch)} level={level + 1}/>
                
        {:else}
                <p>branch</p>
        {/if}
{/each}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i upgraded to 4.2.2 and it works